# Integration of a hermitian matrix using the Haar measure

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

For any hermitian $d\times d$ matrix $A$, show that
$$
\int_{\mathrm{U}(d)} UAU^\dagger d\mu(U) = \frac{A+tr(A)I}{d(d+1)},
$$
where $\mathrm{U}(d)$ is the group of unitary $d\times d$ matrices, and $d\mu$ is the Haar measure over that group.

This statement is used in equations (S34) and (S35) from [Huang et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.08953). The authors also refer to another work [Gross et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.2267) (section 3.5), which apparently proves the statement using wiring diagrams. However, this work is too advanced for me.
Anyway, for my purposes I only need to understand this equation for $d=2$ and $d=3$. Therefore my crude approach would be to parametrize $U, A$ and $d\mu$ in order to compute the integral explicitly. I already struggle with that and I am not sure if it is the right way to do it.

Any hint about how to show this for low dimensions would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you you get from (S35) in the linked paper to the expression you've written? The equality in the question appears to be untrue: the LHS is invariant under $U(n)$-conjugation while the RHS is not.

Comment: Oh yes I see it now.. Maybe I misunderstood something. Right below equation (S34) the authors say "The right hand side of this equation [(S34)] can be evaluated explicitly [...] This in turn yields closed-form expressions [...]" and then they show equation (S35). Therefore I understood the RHS of equation (S34) to equal the RHS of equation (S35).